# How to group sessions of 30 minutes with reference initial timestamp on Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

So basically I have a bunch of users that enter in my website and I need them grouped by their sessions. A session is a 30 minutes connection with the same ID since the first login. If it takes more then 30 minutes it's refereed as a new session.

Sample input:

```
id,timestamp_datetime
1,2020-04-25 21:28:57.499 # Session 1 - first session
1,2020-04-25 21:41:41.691 
1,2020-04-25 21:41:11.055
1,2020-04-25 22:00:00.015  # Session 1 - second session (more then 30 minutes)
2,2020-04-25 21:41:41.691  # Session 2 - first session
2,2020-04-25 22:00:00.015 
2,2020-04-25 22:30:03.838  # Session 2 - second session
3,2020-04-25 21:41:41.691
```

Sample output:

```
id, count_sessions
1, 2
2, 2
3, 1
```

I have tried this

```
df.groupby([df.index.to_period('30T'),"id"]).count()
```

But it gave me the wrong results. Please help me fix it.

Comment: Did you solve it? If you provide a sample as https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/6692898 I can give it another go

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
np.ceil(df.groupby('id').diff().cumsum()/30)
```